# How to get variable value by using string

Tags: java, reflection

How to get variable value by using string that i got from xml i.e. "category" this variable  i got from string now i need to have this value in java. I learned about reflection but can anyone explain me how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking, but do you have an object and want to get the value of a specific field via reflection?
Assuming your object reference is "myObject"

```
    Field declaredField = myObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("category");
    System.out.println(declaredField.get(myObject));
```

Note, if the field is not public you might want to

```
    declaredField.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: Don't forget to check if declaredField is null.

Comment: Yeah, and the fact that doing this can throw all kinds of checked exceptions.

Comment: Thanks man!!! You are awesome!!! now can you tell me if that field is inside method how can i access it

Comment: Fields are not inside methods. Only local variables can be declared in methods, and you cannot access those. That is because the compiler might eliminate them and other reasons.

Comment: You are right, ivarni: [getDeclaredField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa989722(v=vs.80).aspx) will throw a NoSuchFieldException, if it can't find it. Make sure to catch that.

Comment: can i get arraylist as a field

Comment: Yes, you can get any kind of object or primitive (and sooner or later that will blow up somewhere). Please realize that this is a very fragile style of programming and use reflection with care.